# How do I select the latest record for each disticnt id in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have a Hive table that looks like the following table

```
ID | Value | Timestamp (epoch)| Status
 1   2300      1516187739     | Active
 1   2500      1516187403     | Stopped
 1   1800      1516187450     | Stopped
 2   1300      1516187730     | Active
 2   1500      1516187780     | Active
```

. I want to get the latest record by looking at the timestamp for each ID when status is active. I want to have only one record per ID. So the result would look like the table below. I am looking for an efficient way to implement this query in Hive.

```
ID | Value | 
 1   2300      
 2   1500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` analytic function for such purpose.

```
 SELECT a.id, a.VALUE
  FROM (SELECT id,
               VALUE,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
                  rn
          FROM yourtable) a
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am getting the following error message: 
*Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:133 cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rn' '=' in subquery source*

Comment: Manos : I cannot simulate the issue as I don&#39;t have a hive db access. The syntax looks fine.you may have to figure out to change the syntax slightly to suit your hive version by trial and error. But the logic to be used remains the same.

Comment: I found the answer. Hive requires alias names for sub queries, I edited the answer.

Comment: @Manos : Great.. all the best!. I'm Glad that it helped you